# Solr - Order results by proximity to number

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I am using solr to get results based on the search text entered by the user.
I want to order the results based on proximity to the calories field of the document as shown below.
I have used Range (calories:[0 TO 300]) however that doesnt fulfill my needs.

```js
{
  "food_group":"Proteins",
  "carbs":"6.295",
  "protein":"13.729",
  "fat":"2.551",
  "calories":103.0
}
```

For example if user enters 100 as calories i want to show the document with 101 before the document with 97 and so on...(There is no sorting logic in this)

Comment: Take a look here. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Function+Queries#FunctionQueries-SortByFunction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use `abs(sub(user_calories, calories))` function as sort**

Example for user input 100 :

```
q = "calories:[0 TO 300]",
sort = "abs(sub(100,calories)) asc"
```

Example Url :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/test/select?q=calories%3A%5B0+TO+300%5D&sort=abs(sub(100%2Ccalories))+asc
```

Comment: this works perfect. I want to do the follwing as well (food_group:"Protein"^boost & abs(sub(100,calories)) asc^boost1) that is i want to apply boost to this sort. Can you tell how to do this.? @Ashraful Islam

Comment: Check boost query and boost function https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser#TheDisMaxQueryParser-Thebq(BoostQuery)Parameter

Comment: i am able to write abs(sub(100,calories))^1 but not abs(sub(100,calories)) asc^1 in bf... @Ashraful Islam.  Also this is the url i am on at the moment - http://localhost:8983/solr/test/select?bf=abs(sub(100,calories))^1&defType=edismax&indent=on&q=( food_group:"Proteins"^100  OR food_group:"Dairy"  OR food_group:"Grains"   )&rows=100&wt=json

Comment: What is the max value of calories ? you can subtract calories from the max value `abs(sub(100,sub(max_value,calories)))`, so your calories will be reversed or use `div(1,abs(sub(100,calories)))`

Comment: I haven't tested it, try this and let me know

Comment: div(1,abs(sub(100,calories))) this one worked perfect! Thank you very much.

Comment: Or use  `abs(sub(100,rord(calories)))`

Comment: This gave an error -unexpected docvalues type NUMERIC for field 'calories' (expected one of [SORTED, SORTED_SET]). Re-index with correct docvalues type

Comment: I am putting this to your new question so that other user may find it useful

Comment: Yes that will be great.